# Nonlinear Optimization - Function involving Ax and b

Tags: optimization, least-squares, positive-definite, quadratic-programming, hessian-matrix

I have been struggling with a practice problem for some time now. Here is the problem:

$f(x) = |Ax-b|^{2}$

$A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix with zero null space, b is an $m$ dimensional vector and $x$ is an n dimensional vector.

Find the hessian, and prove it is positive definite. Then, find a closed form expression for the global minimizer $x^{*}$. Some other questions but these are the ones causing problems for me.

I am struggling a lot with this question. My approach was as follows:

Write $f(x)$ without the matrices and vectors. So

$f(x) = (\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{1k}x_{k}-b_{1})^{2} +...+(\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{mk}x_{k}-b_{m})^{2}$

Then I computed the hessian by just taking second derivatives. It looks like this (confirm/deny?)

$\begin{bmatrix}
 \sum_{l=1}^{m}a_{l1}^{2}  .  ....................  \sum_{l=1}^{m}a_{l1}a_{ln} \\ 
 \sum_{l=1}^{m}a_{l1}a_{l2}  ............................. \\ 
....................................... \\ 
........................................\\ 
..........................\sum_{l=1}^{m}a_{ln}^{2} 
\end{bmatrix}$

Assuming this is correct, I am unsure of how to show it is positive definite. (Previously I've mostly used Sylvester's Criterion to show this but it doesnt seem to work here - not easily anyways)

I am also unsure of how to find a closed form for the minimizer.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot

Comment: $$\|A x - b\|_2^2 = (A x - b)^T (A x - b)$$ Do not complicate what is simple.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Writing it in that form makes sense, but I'm still not sure how to continue with the question from this starting point. What am I missing here?

Comment: Nevermind - just have to get a bit more familiar with some matrix calculus but I should be ok. Thanks again for your help